# Transpose Data from two columns to match dates

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am pretty new to VBA and am at a dead end. I have the following data:

| Date | Activity | Sessions | Conversions | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 | Activity 1 | 0 | 0 | £100 |
| 2/1/2021 | Activity 2 | 0 | 0 | £1005 |
| 1/1/2021 |  | 222 | 1 | £0 |
| 2/1/2021 |  | 21312 | 43 | £0 |
| 3/1/2021 |  | 34567 | 23 | £0 |

And am needing the data to look like the following:

| Date | Sessions | Conversions | Activity 1 | Activity 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 | 222 | 1 | £100 |  |
| 2/1/2021 | 21312 | 43 |  | £1005 |
| 3/1/2021 | 34567 | 23 |  |  |

The other issue is the amount of 'Print Activity' may vary, and could be at any date.

I am thinking this could be done using a pivot table?

Any advice would be amazing! Thank you!

I so far have used VBA to make a pivot table, however the results do not work! the code I have is as follows:

```
Sub createPivotTableNewSheet()
    Dim myFirstRow As Long
    Dim myLastRow As Long
    Dim myFirstColumn As Long
    Dim myLastColumn As Long
    Dim mySourceData As String
    Dim myDestinationRange As String
    Dim mySourceWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim myDestinationWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim myPivotTable As PivotTable
    With ActiveWorkbook
        Set mySourceWorksheet = .Worksheets("Date")
        Set myDestinationWorksheet = .Worksheets.Add
    End With
    myDestinationRange = myDestinationWorksheet.Range("A1").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
    myFirstRow = 1
    myLastRow = 20005
    myFirstColumn = 1
    myLastColumn = 5
    With mySourceWorksheet.Cells
        mySourceData = .Range(.Cells(myFirstRow, myFirstColumn), .Cells(myLastRow, myLastColumn)).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
    End With
    Set myPivotTable = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=mySourceWorksheet.Name & "!" & mySourceData).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=myDestinationWorksheet.Name & "!" & myDestinationRange, TableName:="OA Data Pivot")
    With myPivotTable
        .PivotFields("Date").Orientation = xlRowField
    .RowGrand = False
    .ColumnGrand = False
        
 
With .PivotFields(“Activity”)
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
End With
        With .PivotFields("Sessions")
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Position = 1
            .Function = xlSum
            .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
        End With
        With .PivotFields("Conversions ")
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Position = 2
            .Function = xlSum
            .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
        End With
With .PivotFields("Cost")
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .NumberFormat = "£#,##0.00"
        End With  
 myPivotTable.DataPivotField.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField;
  End With
        myDestinationWorksheet.Name = "OA Data Pivot"
End Sub
```

Comment: "do not work" is not a super-useful description of what happens when you run your code.  Do you have `Option Explicit` at the top of your code module?  I see a few "smart quotes" in there which will cause problems which might be flagged up by that setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

***Note:** If your sample is not truly representative of your actual data, a different algorithm may be required.*

***M Code***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

//set the data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Date", type date}, 
        {"Activity", type text}, 
        {"Sessions", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Conversions", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Cost", type text}}),

//Group by date, then extract relevant info by date
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Date"}, {
    
    //First entry in the date column of the subtable
        {"Activity", each [Activity]{0}, type nullable text},

    //Sessions and Conversions can be obtained either from the 2nd row, or as the sum of both rows  
        {"Sessions", each List.Sum([Sessions]), Int64.Type}, 
        {"Conversions", each List.Sum([Conversions]), Int64.Type}, 

    //Cost with the £ symbol is imported as text.  We extract it from the first row.
    // If need to do math operations on it, can convert it to a number.
        {"Cost", each [Cost]{0}, type nullable text}}),

    
    //Then pivot on the activity column, removing any nulls from the pivot column
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Grouped Rows", List.RemoveNulls(List.Distinct(#"Grouped Rows"[Activity])), "Activity", "Cost")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]